# Update array of strings in function

Tags: arrays, c, memory-management

I have a working example of copy lines from a file into an array of strings. I want to move the code to copy the lines into a function to which I simply pass a pointer to the array of strings, where the lines will be stored, and a pointer to the file. However, I have tried to move the code into a function and keep getting seg faults. I have tried debugging using GDB and it seems like the problem is with the memory allocation to `rows`. But I can't work out what the problem is. realloc seems to be working correctly since I find the size of row increases on the 3rd iteration (using malloc_usable_size(*rows)), but then seg faults. I'm compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -g c_programs/read_file_function.c` on Linux.

Working example

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please supply a file path:\n%s <file path>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!fp)
  {
    perror("ERROR");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char **rows = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
  char *lineBuf = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  size_t nLines = 0;
  ssize_t lineLength = 0;
  size_t i = 0;

  while ((lineLength = getline(&lineBuf, &n, fp)) != -1)
  {
    lineBuf[strcspn(lineBuf, "\n")] = 0;
    lineBuf[strcspn(lineBuf, "\r")] = 0;

    rows[i] = (char *)malloc(lineLength + 1);
    strcpy(rows[i], lineBuf);
    i++;
    nLines = i;
    rows = (char **)realloc(rows, (nLines + 1) * sizeof(char *));
  }

  printf("nLines: %lu\n", nLines);
  printf("row 1: %s\n", rows[0]);
  printf("row 2: %s\n", rows[1]);
  printf("row 2: %s\n", rows[10]);

  return 0;
}
```

Non working function version

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t readFile(FILE **fp, char ***rows)
{
  char *lineBuf = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  size_t nLines = 0;
  ssize_t lineLength = 0;
  size_t i = 0;

  while ((lineLength = getline(&lineBuf, &n, *fp)) != -1)
  {
    lineBuf[strcspn(lineBuf, "\n")] = 0;
    lineBuf[strcspn(lineBuf, "\r")] = 0;

    *rows[i] = (char *)malloc(lineLength + 1);
    strcpy(*rows[i], lineBuf);
    i++;
    nLines = i;
    *rows = (char **)realloc(*rows, (nLines + 1) * sizeof(char *));
  }
  return nLines;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  if (argc != 2)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Please supply a file path:\n%s <file path>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (!fp)
  {
    perror("ERROR");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  char **rows = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *));
  size_t nLines = readFile(&fp, &rows);

  printf("nLines: %lu", nLines);
  printf("row 1: %s", rows[0]);
  printf("row 2: %s", rows[1]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ***` do not be a 3-star programmer. Use a structure.

Comment: fp doesn't need to be a **pointer, a *pointer is enough. Using a structure is just hiding a level of pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*rows[i]` is doing `*(rows[i])` - accessing `i`th element in the array of rows, and then dereferencing it. You want to do `(*rows)[i]` - dereference `rows` and then access `i`th element.

I advise to:

```
readFile(..., char ***rows0) {
    char **rows = NULL; // temporary internal variable

    ...
       // use rows normally
       rows = stuff();
    ...
   
    // when finished, assign once
    *rows0 = rows;
    return nLines;
}
```

But do not be a [3-star programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). At best, use a structure, `->` is easy to use. Like:

```
struct string {
    char *str;
};

struct lines {
    struct string *strs;
    size_t cnt;
};


// @return 0 on success, otherwise error
int readFile(...., struct lines *p) {
    // initialization
    p->cnt = 0;
    p->strs = NULL;

    ...
       void *pnt = realloc(p->strs, (p->cnt + 1) * ....);
       if (!pnt) { /* handle error */ return -1; }
       p->strs = pnt;
       p->strs[p->cnt]->str = malloc(lineLenght + 1);
       if (!p->strs[p->cnt]->str) { /* handle error */ return -2; }
       strcpy(p->strs[p->cnt]->str, lineBuf);
       p->cnt++;
    ...

    return 0; /* success */
}
    

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   struct lines p = {0};
   if (readFile(..., &p)) {
       /* handle error */
   }
   printf("nLines: %zu\n", p.cnt);
```

Do not pre-allocate memory. Initialize memory with `NULL` and call `realloc` *before* using memory. `realloc(NULL` is the same as `malloc()`.

Check for allocation errors.